# $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is analytic

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, analyticity

Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is analytic, i.e. that $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ can be approximated in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ by a power series centred at $x_0$.

---

Is it possible to explicitly find such a power series? I tried some transformations using the geometric series, but without success.

Note that I do not yet know that holomorphic functions are analytic.

This [question has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3007301/730592), but I do not understand the solution.

Comment: @nicomezi This is only for $|x|<1$, isn't it?

Comment: You probably know how to write $1/(x-a)$ as a power series centered at $x_0\neq a$. Use that and the partial fraction expansion
$$\frac{i}{x+i}+\frac{-i}{x-i}=\frac2{x^2+1}.$$ The imaginary parts of the sum of two series cancel each other. By complex analysis the resulting series has radius of convergence $\sqrt{x_0^2+1}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is the power serier of $\frac{1}{x-a}$ centred at $x_0$ equal to $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(a-x_0)^{n+1}}(x-x_0)^n$?

Comment: Zuy, that is very close. I think that your series sums up to $1/(a-x)$ though (so a global sign error). It is a geometric series anyway. Do check what you get at $x=x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$ \frac1{1+\alpha x} = \frac1{1+\alpha x_0+\alpha(x-x_0)} =\frac1{1+\alpha x_0}\times \frac1{1+\frac{\alpha(x-x_0)}{1+\alpha x_0}} = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n\alpha ^n}{(1+\alpha x_0)^{n+1}}(x-x_0)^n$$
Using this for $\alpha = \pm i$ and the expansion $$\frac1{1+x^2} = \frac{1/2}{1+(-i)x} + \frac{1/2}{1+ix}$$
we have
$$ \frac1{1+x^2} = \sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{i^n}{2(1-ix_0)^{n+1}} + \frac{(-i)^n}{2(1+ix_0)^{n+1}}\right)(x-x_0)^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} \Re\left[\frac{i^n}{(1-ix_0)^{n+1}}\right](x-x_0)^n$$
As a sanity check- if $x_0=0$, then we should see that only the even terms survive. This is in fact true since $i^n/(1-ix_0)^{n+1} = i^n$ is purely real if $n$ is even and purely imaginary if $n$ is odd. Further the coefficient of $x^2$ should be $-1$, and $i^2 = -1$.

I would presume the comment of Jyrki is equivalent.

---

*A small update no one asked for* (but I couldn't just leave it at Jyrki's comment...maybe he was thinking about something easier) First note that
$$ \frac{a+ib}i = b -ia. \implies \Re(\frac{z}i) = \Im z. $$
Applying this to $z=i^{n+1}/(1-ix_0)^{n+1}$,
$$\Re\left[\frac{i^n}{(1-ix_0)^{n+1}}\right] = \Im\left[\left(\frac{i}{1-ix_0}\right)^{n+1}\right] = \Im\left[\left(\frac{-1}{i+x_0}\right)^{n+1}\right] = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{d(i,x_0)^n}\Im e^{-i n \theta}=\frac{(-1)^{n}\sin(n \theta)}{d(i,x_0)^n} $$
where $d(i,x_0)=\sqrt{1+x_0^2}$ is the distance between $x_0$ and $i$, and $\theta = \arg(i+x_0) = \arctan(1/x_0)$ is the angle that $i+x_0$ makes with the real axis as a vector.

This isn't really a simpler formula, but its more geometrically meaningful and makes it  mechanically routine to apply the root test for the radius of convergence; there is $n_k\to\infty$ such that $|\sin (n_k\theta)| \in (1/2,1]$, as $\theta$ is never a multiple of $\pi$. Therefore 
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|\sin(n \theta)|^{1/n}}{d(i,x_0)} \ge \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2^{-1/n_k}}{d(i,x_0)} = \frac1{d(i,x_0)}$$
But $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|\sin(n \theta)|^{1/n}}{d(i,x_0)} \le \frac{1}{d(i,x_0)} $ trivially, so the radius of convergence is exactly $d(i,x_0)$, as standard complex analysis might also give.

Comment: Its much easier to prove that the title is true, by the way (so I would've used a different one). Namely, $1+x^2$ is analytic and doesn't vanish on an open set containing the real line; hence $1/(1+x^2)$ is analytic

Comment: How do you know that $1/(1+x^2)$ is analytic if $1+x^2$ is?

Comment: Its complex differentiable by the theorem that looks almost exactly like the 1D real variable inverse function theorem, this implies analytic

Comment: Oh, @Zuy , with regards to your specific circumstance and "Note that I do not yet know that holomorphic functions are analytic.", one normally proves this part of the theory first...

Comment: Alright, but as stated above, I cannot use the fact that holomorphic implies analytic.

Comment: Yup, it's the same. I was hoping to be able to simplify the coefficients, but I didn't spot a way. Anyway, from your last form we can also say quite a bit about the radius of convergence :-)